# Complicate dictionary sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort a list like this:

```
# Basically alphabetic order with z in the second place.
order_list = ['a', 'z', 'b', 'c', ..., 'y'] 

# Original dict (I should have more than these but I stop at 'h' for demonstration)
d = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1, 0], 'd': [1, 1], 'e': [2, 3], 'g': [5, 0], 'h': [2, 0], ...}

''' 
sorting order:
1. sum(d.values()[1]): greater the better -> [3,1] > [1,2]
2. max(d.values()[1]): EACH ELEMENTS greater the better -> [2,2] > [3,1] ## notice that [4,2] would still be better than [9,1] since min([4,2]) > min([9,1])
3. order.index(d.values()[0]): follows the order_list
'''

# The result should be:
d = {'e': [2, 3], 'd': [1, 1], 'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1, 0], 'g': [5, 0], 'h': [2, 0]}
```

my attempt was:

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=(
    lambda item: (sum(item[1]),
                  -min(item[1]),  # The problem occurs here*
                  order.index(item[0])))))
```

*Since they're same item[1], it overwrites the previous one!
How can I fix the code?

(ps. edited, it was min)

Comment: You should use `min` and not `max` as the second criterion.

Comment: Also, It is not possible to sort a dictionary, only to get a representation of a dictionary that is sorted using a list(for e.g.).

Comment: Yeah right I realise the mistake right after I posted it sry. The only problem now is that it overwrites the previous command and completely re-sort the dict. Is it possible to keep the previous step's result as the next command run.

Comment: @prnvbn That's not true - starting in `python3.7`, dicts are guaranteed to be ordered in insertion order; that means that iterating on a dict is guaranteed to follow that order.

Comment: So, uhm, do you still have a question? Or is the problem solved? It's hard to tell from the way you edited your question. (In general we don't encourage editing the question to add the answer inside the question itself - please keep the question and answer separate).

Comment: @Stef they question is still how do I code to achieve the desired output with the following steps, I was explaining how my think process and where the code went wrong tho..